# Highcharts - mouse event in chart - e.Offset solution across browsers

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jquery

I have to identify if the mouseup even is inside the chart or not and display the point's co-ordinates. The following code works well in chrome but not in firefox as firefox does not have `event.offset` property.

```
  jQuery(chart.container).mouseup(function (event) {
     eoffsetX=event.offsetX;
     eoffsetY=event.offsetY;
     if (eoffsetX > chartX.plotLeft && eoffsetX < chartX.plotLeft + chartX.plotWidth && eoffsetY > chartX.plotTop && eoffsetY < chartX.plotTop + chartX.plotHeight) {
        alert ("The clicked x,y point is "+chart.xAxis[0].toValue(eoffsetX, 0)+" , " + chart.yAxis[0].toValue(eoffsetY, 0));
     }
```

So I modified the code by looking at few answers on the net, but it still does not work for firefox / IE:

```
  jQuery(chart.container).mouseup(function (event) {
      if(event.offsetX === undefined) {
            eoffsetX=(event.clientX - jQuery(event.target).offset().left);
            eoffsetY=(event.clientY - jQuery(event.target).offset().top);
        }
        else {
            eoffsetX=event.offsetX;
            eoffsetY=event.offsetY;
        }
     if (eoffsetX > chartX.plotLeft && eoffsetX < chartX.plotLeft + chartX.plotWidth && eoffsetY > chartX.plotTop && eoffsetY < chartX.plotTop + chartX.plotHeight) {
        alert ("The clicked x,y point is "+chart.xAxis[0].toValue(eoffsetX, 0)+" , " + chart.yAxis[0].toValue(eoffsetY, 0));
     }
```

Any solutions that will work across browsers please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I got teh answer a few minutes after I posted the question... posting the solution for others who may need it:

Simply replace

`jQuery(event.target).offset().left` to `jQuery(this).offset().left`

and

`jQuery(event.target).offset().top` to `jQuery(this).offset().top`

And cheerio it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
 var offsetX = typeof(e.offsetX)==='undefined' ? e.clientX:e.offsetX,
     offsetY = typeof(e.offsetY)==='undefined' ? e.clientY:e.offsetY;
```

Comment: but instead of "e.clientX" I should use "e.clientX-jQuery(this).offset().left". Also since there are two compare statements this should be less efficient than having one compare, tho it looks tidier.

Comment: All depends on you, it is only suggestion ;)